# Invalid paths using CloudFront create invalidation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cache-invalidation

I am trying to invalidate CloudFront objects in C#/.NET and gettign the following exception:

> Your request contains one or more invalid invalidation paths.

My Function:

```
public bool InvalidateFiles(string[] arrayofpaths)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayofpaths.Length; i++)
    {
        arrayofpaths[i] = Uri.EscapeUriString(arrayofpaths[i]);
    }

    try
    {
        Amazon.CloudFront.AmazonCloudFrontClient oClient = new Amazon.CloudFront.AmazonCloudFrontClient(MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        CreateInvalidationRequest oRequest = new CreateInvalidationRequest();
        oRequest.DistributionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudFrontDistributionId"];
        oRequest.InvalidationBatch = new InvalidationBatch
        {
            CallerReference = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(),
            Paths = new Paths
            {
                Items = arrayofpaths.ToList<string>(),
                Quantity = arrayofpaths.Length
            }
        };

        CreateInvalidationResponse oResponse = oClient.CreateInvalidation(oRequest);
        oClient.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The array passed to the function contains a single Url like so:

```
images/temp_image.jpg
```

The image exists in the S3 bucket and loaded in the browser in the CloudFront URL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Invalid invalidation! It's Invalidception! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send invalidation request to some object in CloudFront, you still can see your picture in the browser in the CloudFront URL even when invalidation completed, because invalidation does not delete object from S3 bucket and with new request to this image from you browser CloudFront again cached these URl to images/temp_image.jpg in edge locations.

Invalidation of object will be seen, when you update image with the same name.

Your Invalidation function is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You invalidation file paths need a / at the front of the string.

If you are in doubt, you can log onto AWS Management, go to Cloudfront, select the distribution you are trying to invalidate files from, select Distribution setting and go to the Invalidations tab.

You can then create validations manually, which allows you to check that your paths are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding the forward slash at the beginning of the path? (/images/temp_image.jpg)

Comment: The documentation says otherwise. Quote, "A leading / is optional." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: The documentation has been updated to indicate that a leading slash is now required. "In the CloudFront console, you can omit the leading slash in the path, like this: images/image2.jpg. When you use the CloudFront API directly, invalidation paths must begin with a leading slash." Source: [Invalidating files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)